# laravel 5 foreach key not working in controller

Tags: php, foreach, image-upload, laravel-5.6

```
$input=$request->file('file');
dd($input)
    $images=array();
    $editname=array();

        foreach($input as $index => $file)
        {
            $extention= $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $editname='Question'.$index.'.'.$extention.'';
            $file->storeAs('public',$editname);
            $images[]=$name;
            $url=Storage::url($editname);
            DB::table('images')->insert(['name'=>$editname]);

        }
```

The above code allows me to loop through multiple images and store within the storage. I need to assign the array element key in to the name, but when foreach is run `$index` is always `0`. why is this.
`dd($input)` gives,

```
array:1 [
0 => UploadedFile {#445
-test: false
-originalName: "download.png"
-mimeType: "image/png"
-size: 22581
-error: 0
#hashName: null
path: "C:\xampp\tmp"
filename: "phpEF90.tmp"
basename: "phpEF90.tmp"
pathname: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpEF90.tmp"
extension: "tmp"
realPath: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpEF90.tmp"
aTime: 2018-03-13 09:46:02
mTime: 2018-03-13 09:46:02
cTime: 2018-03-13 09:46:02
inode: 0
size: 22581
perms: 0100666
owner: 0
group: 0
type: "file"
writable: true
readable: true
executable: false
file: true
dir: false
link: false
linkTarget: "C:\xampp\tmp\phpEF90.tmp"
```

}
]

Comment: show us a `dd($index)` befre your foreach loop

Comment: Did your form has many file field?

Comment: @yvesdaxmaz i am using vue-clip to send the images. the 'paramName' is `file[]`

Comment: @kevinniel `dd($index)` gives me `cors` error do you know why this is. my laravel already has a `CORS middleware` that allows all headers to be accepted

Comment: what does `dd($input)` gives you (after the first line)

Comment: @kevinniel the `dd($input)` is posted in the question

Comment: Yup didnt see sry. The thing is your input array is containing only one row. So the first index of an array is "0" so the result seems logic... meaning that the problem comes from your input field

Comment: @kevinniel yah i see that now thanks but to upload multiple images this code works. Do you have another method to get the index into the image

Comment: I don't think i understand what you're calling "index"... The index in you code is your array index. And it's set to 0, and you got a 0. So all is logical. What "information" do you call index ? what do you want in your image name ? which var ? which value ?

Comment: @kevinniel i want the image names to be `Question1,Question2` and so on where the numbers is the index

Comment: Then why don't you just set a var ?? like $i = 1; and then at the end of foreach loop you increment it $i++ and put it in the name no ?

Comment: @kevinniel yah i did that too still not working just gives me `1` when i give `$num=1;` and `$num++;`. i think something wrong with my foreach its not looping